# Recipe for enchanted armor/weapon

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

I want to create a recipe for vanilla items, but that they are crafted with certain enchantments. What fields do I need to specify for this?

I've read [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389671/enchanting-items-in-a-custom-crafting-recipe), but the problem is that the answer is about food that gives effects, not about enchantments on the armor

Comment: this is currently not possible on bedrock using the built-in recipe system, but it might be possible to create your own (maybe throwing the items on the ground?). If I find a way to do it, I will let you know

Comment: @Jmooroof but how do i create an item with enchants?

Answer (score 2):

Like @Jmooroof said, this isn't possible with the system as it is right now. However, here is a workaround you could use.

You could create a recipe that gives an item a ridiculous data value (integer), then run a command (`/enchant`) in a repeating command block with the `hasitem` selector. Example below. (Note: this does not work on items such as wool, concrete, and boats that use data values to determine the variant of the item).

Crafting Recipe (`behavior_pack/recipes/enchanted_diamond_sword.json`)

```
{
  "format_version": "1.19.0",
  "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:item"
    },
    "tags": [
      "crafting_table"
    ],
    "pattern": [
      "X",
      "X",
      "l"
    ],
    "key": {
      "X": {
        "item": "minecraft:diamond"
      },
      "l": {
        "item": "minecraft:stick"
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "item": "minecraft:diamond_sword",
      "data": 7776
    }
  }
}
```

Repeating Command Block

```
# Enchant the sword of all players with data=7776 with sharpness 5.
enchant @a[hasitem={item=diamond_sword,data=7776}] sharpness 5
```

I have not tested this, but I believe it would work.